# Error Signing P2SH-P2WSH MultiSig - "Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)"

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, segregated-witness, multi-signature, bitcoin-cli

I am trying to create and spend a P2SH-P2WSH transaction using `bitcoin-cli` but am getting **"Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)"** when I try to sign the Multi-Sig transaction using `bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey ...`

Here is the shell script I am using to create and sign the transaction:

https://gist.github.com/praveenbm5/e39be366bebbab71ec29342722f5c29b

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' bitcoin_conf <<-EOM
## Generated - `date`
## bitcoin.conf configuration file. Lines beginning with # are comments.
##
daemon=1
regtest=1

listen=0

# JSON-RPC options (for controlling a running Bitcoin/bitcoind process)
rpcuser=coinvault
rpcpassword=my_hen_lays_two_eggs_a_day
rpcport=8332

# server=1 tells Bitcoin-Qt and bitcoind to accept JSON-RPC commands
server=1
#prune=5500
txindex=1
EOM

echo $bitcoin_conf > ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

set -x #echo on

start afresh
rm -R ~/.bitcoin/regtest
bitcoind

#Depositor - Keys
DepositorAdrs="2NDHneT24Kv2WBEdR3bK12Esx22Lwt269Sq"
DepositorPriv="cUrRAGYGV9Lj7yk7qFMZxxVeFTFqgt6BuJheb4EgVMafHef8f9p9"
DepositorPub="023320c921fb86d276cf996c97a3f3893e5da2c03926acd1d5160d0ccdb582f416"
#DepositorToken - Keys
DepositorTokenAdrs="2N5MtkMHE6LdEPmFcAt8E7dUVdYFSZbpJhz"
DepositorTokenPriv="cTXijGDBz6jDD2tKarpt982e4VnF7Jm1uJg5oKsVSpzcL8y3ut63"
DepositorTokenPub="032aa651b6e0064cf4ddc0230e5cf37496d32e7970e9221f0d16d7afefd2be2451"
#Vault - Keys
VaultAdrs="2MtfrYeMAZSMZMZhWbpt6RyCsKfbQ4YTGm1"
VaultPriv="cS71P5KPZbgGYhkXfTomFNYxq2NRccQb8Zkw3XEQkMVnQdSvAYQn"
VaultPub="03cb7ef39e4bf4e487f73dd8c0ac6f0ef112a6ac7b3fa09546007121605bfa7c7b"
#VaultToken - Keys
VaultTokenAdrs="2NBNydtkbBZ4cpVPmQai5M7HPaCTG2TtiMG"
VaultTokenPriv="cSU3xYnsJuojZiuaoJs6tBP8dA5MUL67kwwPvh2hwgQVuByGUJ7u"
VaultTokenPub="0380f1bd8cfc7560dc0a0da73d121d7ff7e9c63464321d3fb6758c400dcbc021a2"

bitcoin-cli generatetoaddress 101 "2NDHneT24Kv2WBEdR3bK12Esx22Lwt269Sq"
bitcoin-cli importaddress "2NDHneT24Kv2WBEdR3bK12Esx22Lwt269Sq"

utxo_txid_1=$(bitcoin-cli listunspent | jq -r '.[0] | .txid')
utxo_vout_1=$(bitcoin-cli listunspent | jq -r '.[0] | .vout')

# Create Deposit Transaction

DepositTxOutputAddress="2N5WCSHb1jzz1DWY7bSc6oW4Q918R6teLvc"
DepositTxRedeemScript="002077ed8a9258123317cfe7c30a8990b4c7ef4fe011e26c1dbe5838466dd4633c08"
DepositTxWitnessScript="0072537a532103cb7ef39e4bf4e487f73dd8c0ac6f0ef112a6ac7b3fa09546007121605bfa7c7b21032aa651b6e0064cf4ddc0230e5cf37496d32e7970e9221f0d16d7afefd2be245121023320c921fb86d276cf996c97a3f3893e5da2c03926acd1d5160d0ccdb582f41653ae"

# bitcoin-cli decodescript $DepositTxWitnessScript
#
# {
#   "asm": "0 OP_2SWAP 3 OP_ROLL 3 03cb7ef39e4bf4e487f73dd8c0ac6f0ef112a6ac7b3fa09546007121605bfa7c7b 032aa651b6e0064cf4ddc0230e5cf37496d32e7970e9221f0d16d7afefd2be2451 023320c921fb86d276cf996c97a3f3893e5da2c03926acd1d5160d0ccdb582f416 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
#   "type": "nonstandard",
#   "p2sh": "2MzCj5bQ67x3vsy5GZnHeE5oezZnzvK62GT",
#   "segwit": {
#     "asm": "0 77ed8a9258123317cfe7c30a8990b4c7ef4fe011e26c1dbe5838466dd4633c08",
#     "hex": "002077ed8a9258123317cfe7c30a8990b4c7ef4fe011e26c1dbe5838466dd4633c08",
#     "reqSigs": 1,
#     "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
#     "addresses": [
#       "bcrt1qwlkc4yjczge30nl8cv9gny95clh5lcq3ufkpm0jc8prxm4rr8syqw6ctdw"
#     ],
#     "p2sh-segwit": "2N5WCSHb1jzz1DWY7bSc6oW4Q918R6teLvc"
#   }
# }

read -r -d '' DepositTxInputs <<-EOM
    [
        {
            "txid": "$utxo_txid_1",
            "vout": $utxo_vout_1
        }
    ]
EOM

read -r -d '' DepositTxOutputs <<-EOM
    [
        {
            "$DepositTxOutputAddress": 50
        }
    ]
EOM


DepositTx=$(bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction "$DepositTxInputs" "$DepositTxOutputs")

echo "Unsigned Deposit Tx"
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$DepositTx"

DepositTxSigned=$(bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey "$DepositTx"  "[\"$DepositorPriv\"]" | jq -r '.hex')

echo "Signed Deposit Tx"
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$DepositTxSigned"

DepositTxID=$(bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$DepositTxSigned" | jq .txid)
DepositTxScriptPubKey=$(bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$DepositTxSigned" | jq '.vout[0] | .scriptPubKey.hex')


ProvTxOutputAddress="2MtBFk78tB3awCMREc2KBy93WAUT9ZxGc2Y"

read -r -d '' ProvTxInputs <<-EOM
    [
        {
            "txid": $DepositTxID,
            "vout": 0
        }
    ]
EOM

read -r -d '' ProvTxOutputs <<-EOM
    [
        {
            "$ProvTxOutputAddress": 50
        }
    ]
EOM

ProvTx=$(bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction "$ProvTxInputs" "$ProvTxOutputs")

echo "Unsigned Prov Tx"
echo "HEX: $ProvTx"
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$ProvTx"

read -r -d '' PrevTx <<-EOM
    [
        {                            
            "txid": $DepositTxID,        
            "vout": 0,                 
            "scriptPubKey": $DepositTxScriptPubKey,
            "redeemScript": "$DepositTxRedeemScript",     
            "witnessScript": "$DepositTxWitnessScript",
            "amount": 50.00000000         
        }
    ]
EOM

echo "Prev Tx Data for Prov Tx"
echo "$PrevTx" | jq -r .

ProvTxPartSignedDep=$(bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey "$ProvTx"  "[\"$VaultPriv\"]" "$PrevTx")
echo $ProvTxPartSignedDep | jq -r .
ProvTxPartSignedDep=$( echo $ProvTxPartSignedDep | jq -r '.hex')

echo "Vault Signed Prov Tx"
echo "HEX: $ProvTxPartSignedDep"
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$ProvTxPartSignedDep"

ProvTxPartSignedDep=$(bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey "$ProvTxPartSignedDep"  "[\"$DepositorTokenPriv\"]" "$PrevTx")
echo $ProvTxPartSignedDep | jq -r .
ProvTxPartSignedDep=$( echo $ProvTxPartSignedDep | jq -r '.hex')

echo "Vault+DepositorToken Signed Prov Tx"
echo "HEX: $ProvTxPartSignedDep"
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$ProvTxPartSignedDep"

ProvTxPartSignedDep=$(bitcoin-cli signrawtransactionwithkey "$ProvTxPartSignedDep"  "[\"$DepositorPriv\"]" "$PrevTx")
echo $ProvTxPartSignedDep | jq -r .
ProvTxPartSignedDep=$( echo $ProvTxPartSignedDep | jq -r '.hex')

echo "Vault+DepositorToken+Depositor Signed Prov Tx"
echo "HEX: $ProvTxPartSignedDep"
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction "$ProvTxPartSignedDep"

bitcoin-cli stop
```

Comment: To improve the post, can be posted also only the script P2SH?

Comment: I posted the entire setup and flow because I believe the issue may not just be with the P2SH-P2WSH transaction but that way I am trying to do it all using bitcoin-cli and json. I have been struggling with this for more than a week now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a non-standard script with opcodes that are not found in standard scripts. Bitcoin Core cannot sign for non-standard scripts, the signer does not understand them.